# Automatically target the message commit text box when switching to SCM

Tags: visual-studio-code

Do you know if there's a way to automatically focus the commit message text field after opening the SCM panel (by it by clicking the icon with the mouse or by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34959) was fixed with vscode release **v1.17.0**. Neither can I reproduce this behavior with vscode version v1.20.1. So when you are using an earlier vscode version than v1.17.0, **updating will fix it**.

Comment: Hi HaaLeo, thanks for the embellishment of my question and for the answer. I'm on 1.20.1 right now (f88bbf9137d24d36d968ea6b2911786bfe103002) and still experimenting the issue.

Comment: Are you using some custom kind of scm extension or the default one? Also make sure that you have opened the root folder of an already existing git repository. Maybe you can add a screenshot/gif or similar that shows your set up.

Comment: The current behavior is that the SOURCE CONTROL PROVIDERS viewlet is focused, wich is fine. Now, what I would like to focus when I open the SCM pane is the text field where you set the description for the commit.